# Is ASP.NET MVC 2 Bin-deployable?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, asp.net-mvc-2

I know that ASP.NET MVC 1.0 is bin-deployable as explained in Phil Haack's [article.](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Is ASP.NET MVC 2.0 also bin-deployable? Has anyone done this already that can point out potential pitfalls specific to version 2.0 if there are any?

I would like to deploy a relatively simple ASP.NET MVC 2.0 onto a Windows 2008 Web server that does not have ASP.NET MVC 2.0 installed. It is running .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have deployed a MVC 2 application and it works fine! The release is at RTM and would suggest that its bug-free, with a few child-problems i guess! =)

If your server (IIS7) or similar dont have MCV.dll you have to choose on your .dll (Copy Local: Always)

Comment: Finally rolled this out to the server today and the bin deployment worked just fine.

I also asked about this on Scott Guthrie's blog and got confirmation from him that it is bin-deployable as well. 

Scott's response is in the comments section and dated Monday, March 22, 2010 6:45 PM on his ASP.NET MVC 2 Released post.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/11/asp-net-mvc-2-released.aspx